# Is there something similar to AnomalyDetection (R) for Python users?

Tags: python, r, time-series, statsmodels

It's quite easy to detect anomalies in time series with [this package](https://blog.twitter.com/2015/introducing-practical-and-robust-anomaly-detection-in-a-time-series) (only one line of code):

```
res = AnomalyDetectionTs(raw_data, max_anoms=0.02, direction='both', plot=TRUE)
```

I was wondering whether there's something similar for Python or not. I couldn't find anything reasonably simple in *statsmodel*: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/tsa.html

Comment: maybe [scipy.signal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) has something (e.g. peak finding at the bottom)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your interest, we don't currently have a python version of our AnomalyDetection package, though you'd probably be able to get it going using Rpy2: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/

Best,

Comment: The most optimal workflow may be to manage your data inputs in Pandas and save to a .csv and dump the anoms and plot outputs into a .csv/.png file after you run Rpy2. This would mean that you'd only be pulling in one package into R.